# Select Particular column using jsstore from indexeddb

Tags: indexeddb

I used below code selecting all columns from indexeddb

```
this._connection.openDb(this._indexedDBLiveDBName);
        return this._connection.select({
            From: this._indexedDBLiveDBArticleTableName,
            Where: {
                ChildName: section
            }
        });
```

But I need to select all columns except one column can i do that.If means pls provide an example

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your result is -

```
results = [
    {
        _id : a,
        _name : "fr",
        _gender : "m",
        _country : "efr",
        _city : ""
    }
]
```

Now you only want - _id, _name in the results

so way to achieve above situation will be :

1. you can create new results out of existing result -

`

```
var newResults = [];
    results.forEach(function (item) {
        newResults.push({
           _id:item._id,
           _name:item._name
       })
   });
```

`

2. You can remove the property from the existing results -

`

```
results.forEach(function (item) {
        delete item._country;
        delete item._city;
        delete item._gender;
        delete item._country
    })
```

`

Comment: Thanks,I have stored blob also in my table.Before Fetching blob,it was fine.After selecting blob fetching is very slow.so,that I am asking for this solution(Selecting particular column).

Comment: yes storing blob will slow the retrieve as its heavy sized data. Better to store  files on server and store the file url in jsstore.